# why mvn install failed?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am working in a multi module project.  I go into the only module (feature) which does not have dependency. I run the command :
`mvn clean` it's works
`mvn install` it's failed
I don't understand why, here i have the stacktrace :

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.624s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 03 14:51:00 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myapp:com.myapp.feature.api:bundle:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project com.myapp.feature.api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myapp:com.myapp.feature.api:bundle:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myapp:com.myapp.feature.api:bundle:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:528)
    ... 26 more
```

If someone could explain me ou give me some ideas where to look, it will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT". You need to install that module first, ok place it in a central repos.

Comment: What is your com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT? can you build and install this first?

Comment: @Stefan my jar in my local reposotory  was deleted but don't know why ?

Comment: @in feature.api i just have some basic pojo which are used by other modules

Comment: If it's a multi-module maven project. Could you please post the structure of your project, including the modules. Maybe the versions in the modules are not in synch with the parent `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Think the message is pretty clear:

```
Could not find artifact com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The artifact `com.myapp:feature.api:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` is not found in your maven repository.

Comment: I am in the project feature, i run mvn install ( it would do the complete cycle compile, test, package and install ?). i don't why jar was deleted. I want to installed the jar of current projet. It is not the right thing to do ?